# Trying to list items using loop and dot notation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

So I'm trying to work out this piece of code. It prints in the console and now I'm trying to get it to run through the loop and list each person and their details, while also using dot notation. I've tried various different options and scoured the web. I'm new to Javascript which could be why I've missed something fairly obvious. Can anyone help please?

```
// jslint devel: true 
var student = [
  { 
   name : 'Peter',
   course : 'Creative Technologies',
   module : 3,
   attendence: 79         
  },

  { 
   name : 'John',
   course : 'Art',
   module : 2,
   attendence : 41         
  }, 

  { 
   name : 'Hannah',
   course : 'Business',
   module : 4,
   attendence : 78        
  },   


  { 
   name : 'Greg',
   course : 'ICT',
   module : 3,
   attendence : 93         
  },   

  { 
   name : 'Sam',
   course : 'Music',
   module : 1,
   attendence : 67         
  },   
];


for (prop in student) {
    console.log(prop, ': ', student[prop]);
}

function print(message){
    document.write(message);
}

 for (var i = 0; i < student.length; i++) {
    name = student[i][name];
    course = student[i][course];
    module = student[i][module];
    attendence = student[i][attendence];
    print();
}
```

Comment: You're calling print() but you don't pass anything to it, but it expects a message

Comment: Also you cannot access properties like this `student[i][name]` because `name` is not defined. Perhaps you meant this? `student[i]["name"]`? And as a tip, don't use `document.write.`

Comment: Thanks for your help men, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want brackets notation in your loop where you're using a string key (`prop`), and you want either dot notation and a literal in the places where you're writing the name literally (`student[i].course`) or if you want to use brackets notation there, you need to put the name in quotes (`student[i]["course"]`). When you do `student[i][course]`, you're saying "Look up the value of the `course` variable and use that as the property name," but you don't have any `course` variable in scope at that point.

With dot notation (and passing something to `print`):

```js
// jslint devel: true 
var student = [
  { 
   name : 'Peter',
   course : 'Creative Technologies',
   module : 3,
   attendence: 79         
  },

  { 
   name : 'John',
   course : 'Art',
   module : 2,
   attendence : 41         
  }, 

  { 
   name : 'Hannah',
   course : 'Business',
   module : 4,
   attendence : 78        
  },   


  { 
   name : 'Greg',
   course : 'ICT',
   module : 3,
   attendence : 93         
  },   

  { 
   name : 'Sam',
   course : 'Music',
   module : 1,
   attendence : 67         
  },   
];

/* Leaving this out to keep the output simple
for (prop in student) {
    console.log(prop, ': ', student[prop]);
}
*/
function print(message){
    console.log(message);
}

 for (var i = 0; i < student.length; i++) {
    var name = student[i].name;              // ***
    var course = student[i].course;          // ***
    var module = student[i].module;          // ***
    var attendence = student[i].attendence;  // ***
    print("Student #" + i + ":");
    print("  name      : " + name);
    print("  course    : " + course);
    print("  module    : " + module);
    print("  attendence: " + attendence);
}
```

---

Side note: The word "attend**a**nce" has an `a` at the end, not an `e`.

Comment: T.J, thanks for your help - that's me sorted now! :)